# How to set x2label for pm3d plot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axis-labels

I want to make a `pm3d` plot with different scales on the x-x2 and y-y2 `axes` (namely 'optical thickness' and 'real thickness'). I can make the tics different on the axes, but the `x2label` and `y2label` are not shown. Could you recommend a solution?

```
n1 = 1.2
n2 = 1.3

set view map

set link x2 via x*670/2/pi/n1 inverse 2*pi/670*n1*x 
set link y2 via y*670/2/pi/n2 inverse 2*pi/670*n2*y 

set xlabel "{/Symbol a}=2{/Symbol p}/{/Symbol l}n_1L" 
set x2label "L_1(n_1) [nm]" 
set ylabel "{/Symbol b}=2{/Symbol p}/{/Symbol l}n_2L" 
set y2label "L_2(n_2) [nm]" 

set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

set x2tics 100
set y2tics 100

unset colorbox

splot sin(x)*y**2 w pm3d
```

[image: plot without x2 and y2label]

I have a manual solution with something like:

```
set label 1 at screen 0.95, screen 0.5 "L_2(n_2) [nm]" rotate by 90
```

but it is not the best way I think.

[image: manual solution]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a known bug which will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was turn out, that is a bug in version 5.2. It will be fixed in release 5.4.4.

https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2519/

https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2484/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `splot w pm3d` you probably could use `plot w image`.
Right away, I couldn't find any useful information in gnuplot help why there is no x2label in a "3D"-plot. Maybe there is and I just haven't found it.

**Script:**

```
### plot a map via "plot w image" instead of "splot w pm3d"
reset session

set xlabel  "{/Symbol a}=2{/Symbol p}/{/Symbol l}n_1L" 
set x2label "L_1(n_1) [nm]" 
set ylabel  "{/Symbol b}=2{/Symbol p}/{/Symbol l}n_2L" 
set y2label "L_2(n_2) [nm]" 

set xtics nomirror out
set mxtics 2
set ytics nomirror out
set x2tics 200 out
set mx2tics 2
set y2tics 200 out

n1 = 1.2
n2 = 1.3
set link x2 via x*670/2/pi/n1 inverse 2*pi/670*n1*x 
set link y2 via y*670/2/pi/n2 inverse 2*pi/670*n2*y 

unset colorbox
set urange[-10:10]
set vrange[-10:10]
set samples 100
set isosamples 100

plot '++' u 1:2:(sin($1)*$2**2) w image
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]